# How do I stop XElement.Save from escaping characters?

Tags: c#, xml, escaping, xelement

I'm populating an `XElement` with information and writing it to an xml file using the `XElement.Save(path)` method. At some point, certain characters in the resulting file are being escaped - for example, `>` becomes `&gt;`.

This behaviour is unacceptable, since I need to store information in the XML that includes the `>` character as part of a password. How can I write the 'raw' content of my XElement object to XML without having these escaped?

Comment: If you use the XElement.Load(path), the &gt; will switch back to >.  Can you clarify your problem?

Comment: In that case, it looks like the existing receiving code is where the problem lies. Is there a case where XML could be read into an XElement without the unescaping taking place?

Comment: is your receiving code using XML, or strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XML specification usually allows `>` to appear unescaped. `XDocument` plays it safe and escapes it although it appears in places where the escaping is not strictly required.

You can do a replace on the generated XML. Be aware per http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml#syntax, if this results in any `]]>` sequences, the XML will not conform to the XML specification. Moreover, `XDocument.Parse` will actually reject such XML with the error "']]>' is not allowed in character data.".

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse("<test>Test&gt;Data</test>");
// Don't use this if it could result in any ]]> sequences!
string s = doc.ToString().Replace("&gt;", ">");
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"c:\path\test.xml", s);
```

In consideration that any spec-compliant XML parser must support `&gt;`, I'd highly recommend fixing the code that is processing the XML output of your program.

Comment: I didn't use this, since you're right about the processing code being at fault - but this is the reply that most closely answers the question.

Answer (score 3):

Lack of this behavior is unacceptable.

A standalone unescaped `>` is *invalid XML*.
XElement is designed to produce valid XML.

If you want to get the unescaped *content* of the element, use the `Value` property.

Comment: Actually `>` is usually not required to be escaped. See http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml#syntax for the precise requirement. Nonetheless, I agree with being safe and escaping the `>` all the time. Any parser that conforms to the XML specification is required to understand `&gt;`.

Comment: Is there any case in which the XElement could be induced to provide the raw string (including escaping, as in the file) rather than the unescaped `Value` content? Judging by what you are saying, it sounds like that it is the receiving code that has the problem.