# How to stop XDocument.Save writing escape chars

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm reading XML data from a `varchar column` in a `SQL db`, into a linq to sql `XElement` belonging to an `XDocument`.

When I execute the `XDocument.Save` method, the XML is written to file but includes the escape characters. For example, `">"` is changed to `"&gt"`.

Is there an easy way to prevent this?

Comment: but doesn't that make it not XML?

Comment: This is pretty unclear, sure it gets escaped.  What isn't obvious is why this is a problem or the odds that the escaping happened much earlier, back when the data was inserted in the dbase table.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I stop XElement.Save from escaping characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564396/how-do-i-stop-xelement-save-from-escaping-characters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, there seems to be no reason to prevent it. Like kenny mentioned, unless special characters are XML encoded, no parser would be able to parse produced XML (because '<' or '>' characters means a lot for that parser). Second, when your parser decodes XML (e.g. you call XElement.Value), all special characters will be converted back to what they originally were. Finally, if you want to keep the original string (e.g. for purposes other than XML parsing), you can use CDATA, which in case of Linq2XML is represented by XCData class.

**EDIT**: As Rob pointed out, I might have gotten it wrong. If the point is to save add existing XML to a document, without special characters appear, use the following code:

```
XDocument document = new XDocument();
var xmlFromDb = "<xml>content</xml>";
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlFromDb))) 
{
     using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(stream)) {
          reader.MoveToContent();
          document.Add(XElement.ReadFrom(reader));
     }
}
```

Comment: I think you may be missing the point. The source xml is in the database, but is being escaped when being inserted into the document. The OP wants to insert this as xml, not as "content"